# IE Conditional Statement No Longer Working In IE 11 via Developer Tools

Tags: internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8, page-directives

For some reason the following conditional is not working when I choose IE8 in the Internet Explorer document node and/or user agent.  This worked before.  I am using Internet Explore 11 on Windows 8.1.

```
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
        <p class="alert alert-info chromeframe">You are using an <strong>outdated</strong> browser. Please <a href="http://browsehappy.com/">upgrade your browser</a> or <a href="http://www.google.com/chromeframe/?redirect=true">activate Google Chrome Frame</a> to improve your experience.</p>
    <![endif]-->
```

Answer (score 0):

This bug should be fixed in the latest Windows Update. Let me know if you see issues after installing the update.

The bug is on [connect](http://connect.microsoft.com/IE/feedback/details/806767/conditional-comments-do-not-work-when-emulating-document-modes-via-f12-developer-tools) and you can track it there but it hasn't been update :(.